Issue with Fetching Google Fit Data on Different Accounts & Devices in React Native App
I'm working on a React Native app that uses Google Fitness API to fetch step count, distance, and calorie data. I'm using the react-native-google-fit and @supersami/rn-foreground-service packages. The data fetching works perfectly on my main Google account but fails on other accounts.
Relevant Code (fetchGoogleFit function):
import ...
import ReactNativeForegroundService from '@supersami/rn-foreground-service';
import googleFit from 'react-native-google-fit';

export default function MapActivity() {
  // Google Fit data
  const [steps, setSteps] = useState(0);
  const [distance, setDistance] = useState(0);
  const [calories, setCalories] = useState(0);

  const [startTime, setStartTime] = useState(new Date().toISOString());
  const toggleStarted = () => setToggleActivity(!toggleActivity)
  
  useEffect(() => {  // start task everytime activity is toggled
    if (toggleActivity) {
      startForegroundTask();
      return () => stopForegroundTask();
    }
  }, [toggleActivity]);

  const startForegroundTask = () => {
    console.log('Added tasks');
    ReactNativeForegroundService.add_task(() => fetchGoogleFit(), {
      delay: 1000,
      onLoop: true,
      taskId: 'fetchGoogleFit',
      onError: e => console.log(e),
    });
  };

  const stopForegroundTask = () => {
    console.log('Removed tasks');
    ReactNativeForegroundService.remove_task('fetchGoogleFit');
  };

  const fetchGoogleFit = async () => {
    try {
      let auth = !googleFit.isAuthorized ? await googleFit.authorize() : true;
      console.log('auth:', auth); // log: true
      if (auth) {
        const optSteps = {
          startDate: startTime,
          endDate: new Date().toISOString(),
          bucketUnit: 'DAY',
          bucketInterval: 1,
        };
        const currSteps = await googleFit.getDailyStepCountSamples(optSteps);
        for (let i = 0; i < currSteps.length; i++) {
          if (
            currSteps[i].source === 'com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps' &&
            currSteps[i].steps.length > 0
          ) {
            setSteps(currSteps[i].steps[0].value);
            break;
          }
        }

        const optCalories = {
          startDate: startTime,
          endDate: new Date().toISOString(),
          basalCalculation: true,
          bucketUnit: 'DAY',
          bucketInterval: 1,
        };
        const currCalories = await googleFit.getDailyCalorieSamples(
          optCalories,
        );
        if (currCalories.length > 0) {
          setCalories(parseFloat(currCalories[0].calorie.toFixed(1)));
        }

        const optDistance = {...optSteps};
        const currDistance = await googleFit.getDailyDistanceSamples(
          optDistance,
        );
        if (currDistance.length > 0) {
          setDistance(parseFloat(currDistance[0].distance.toFixed(1)));
        }
      } else {
        console.log('Google Fit authorization failed!');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View>
      ...
    </View>
  );
}

export default MapActivity;

Logs from my Main Google Account - rahulm2053@gmail.com
LOG  [{"rawSteps": [], "source": "com.google.android.gms:merge_step_deltas", "steps": []}, {"rawSteps": [], "source": "com.xiaomi.hm.health", "steps": []}, {
"rawSteps": [[Object]], "source": "com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps", "steps": [[Object]]}]
// The "rawSteps": [[Object]] gives:
LOG  {"rawSteps": [{"dataSourceId": "derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:aggregated", "dataTypeName": "com.google.step_count.delta", "deviceManufacturer": "Xiaomi", "deviceModel": "M2101K6P", "deviceType": "phone", "deviceUid": "d396e761", "endDate": 1719125694043, "originDataSourceId": "raw:com.google.step_count.cumulative:Xiaomi:M2101K6P:d396e761:pedometer  Non-wakeup", "startDate": 1719125651487, "steps": 10}], "source": "com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps", "steps": [{"date": "2024-06-23", "value": 10}]}

LOG  [{"day": "Sun", "distance": 2.0318520069122314, "endDate": "2024-06-23T06:51:03.648Z", "startDate": "2024-06-23T06:51:00.048Z"}]
LOG  [{"calorie": 0.8895832896232605, "day": "Sun", "endDate": "2024-06-23T06:51:14.274Z", "startDate": "2024-06-23T06:50:25.843Z", "wasManuallyEntered": false}]

Logs from Other Google Accounts
LOG  [{"rawSteps": [], "source": "com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps", "steps": []}, {"rawSteps": [], "source": "com.xiaomi.hm.health", "steps": []}, {"rawSteps": [], "source": "com.google.android.gms:merge_step_deltas", "steps": []}]
LOG  []  // distance
LOG  []  // calories

I have provided the necessary permissions while using all accounts.
OAuth Consent Screen
OAuth Consent Screen
Other devices
The issue persists even when I try using the same Google account (rahulm2053@gmail.com) on other devices. Even the account (carevigiltracker@gmail.com) which was used to setup the API on Google Cloud Console does not work. It also does not work even when using the primarily used Google account for that Android device, or any other account.
Works on         - Redmi Note 10 Pro (my main device, running Android 12)
Does not work on - Any other Android device (Android version 12, 13, 14)
It has been tested only on Android, which is my only concern at the moment.
Questions:

Why is the data fetching working for my main Google account but not for others?
Are there any additional permissions or configurations required for other accounts?
How can I ensure consistent data fetching across different Google accounts and devices?

What I've Tried:

Checked Google Fit Permissions: Verified that all necessary permissions are granted on each account.
Re-authorized Google Fit: Attempted reauthorization for the accounts that are not working.
Logged Detailed Data: Added detailed logging to debug data being received from Google Fit.
Project Setup on Google Cloud Console: Ensured the project and API are set up properly on Google Cloud Console with all required configurations and credentials.


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
